# gfortran compiler bug?

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, gfortran

I work in an environment where we have a custom preprocessor for our fortran code.  I use the pre-processor to toggle logical parameters as a sort of poor man's function pointers.  I realized today that I had a situation similar to this:

```
  program main
  logical,parameter :: untrue=.false.
  if(untrue)then
    call func1()
  else
    call func2()
  endif
  end

  subroutine func2()
  print*,"Hello, World!"
  end
```

In other words, `func1` is not anywhere defined, but, this compiles with gfortran (version 4.4 and 4.6) because presumably the compiler optimizes that call away.  I don't have other compilers to check against at the moment, does this code compile elsewhere?  Could/Should this be considered a compiler bug?

Part of the reason I toggle logical switches (instead of including/not including code) is so that the compiler can still check the interface/syntax (if capable) inside that block of code (and issue appropriate warnings for things that aren't simple function calls).  Does this imply those tests aren't being performed or just that the function isn't required by the linker so it all goes through Ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a compiler bug.  The absence of a referenced external subprogram is not something that the standard requires a Fortran processor to diagnose.  Other processors may or may not complain.  Things like optimisation settings may affect the outcome - Intel Fortran 12.1.5 complains with optimisation off and does not complain with optimisation on.

For your example code, where func2 is an external subprogram, Fortran's separate compilation model for program units means that procedure interface checking is not required.  With many processors it is not likely to happen (practically func2 could perhaps be in a separate file that is compiled long after the main program, perhaps on a different machine, perhaps in a situation where the source for the main program is no longer available).  If you want guaranteed procedure interface checking then you need to ensure the procedures have an explicit interface, say by putting them in a module.  The procedure pointer language feature, introduced in the Fortran 2003 standard and supported by gfortran 4.6 at least, may also help.

Comment: thanks.  I can't rely on the newer revisions of the standard at this point.  The code was written 15+ years ago and with the preprocessor the way it is, many f90 constructs could even cause it to break :-(.  I also know about procedure checking needing an interface -- but again, that's not supported by our pre-processor.  I suppose that since the standard doesn't even address the issue of dead-code, anything goes ... Thanks.  (I'll wait a while just to make sure nobody else has anything to say about this, If they don't, I'll gladly accept this.  +1 for a nice answer either way.)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be GNU Fortran specific behaviour that removes unreachable code sections even at optimisation level `O0`. This is consistent with ISO/IEC 1539:1991: §8.1.2 says that only one block of an `IF` construct must get executed and §8.1.1.2 explicitly prohibits transfer of control to the interior of a block from outside the block. This allows the compiler to remove the section of the code that for sure won't execute and it makes sense since you cannot change the behaviour of the `IF` construct in your example without recompiling the program source and the compiler is just being symbol-savvy.

But still I find it strange that `gfortran` does not warn about unreachable code even when compiling with `-Wall -Wunreachable-code`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is simply compiler allowing itself to ignore any references that are never going to be called for. The line:

```
logical,parameter :: untrue=.false.
```

guarantees that the first part of your `if` block is not going to be executed. As IanH pointed out (+1), this is not a compiler bug and is part of the optimization process. This code will also compile with default optimizations with `pgf90 10.6-0` and `ifort 12.0.2.137`. However, they would fail if instructed to compile with no optimization enabled.

However if your line says:

```
logical :: untrue=.false.
```

It is more likely for compilers to complain, as the variable `untrue` is allowed to change its value. For example, `pgf90` will fail unless higher optimization level is required, whereas 'ifort' will still compile on default optimization level.

In any case, it is not best practice to depend on compiler behavior, and, as IanH pointed out, it is always best to specify external function and subroutine interfaces through the use of modules.

Comment: The default optimisation level of `ifort` is `O2` :)